# HFS for Windows by Paragon BSOD

Tags: mac, uninstall, hfs+, paragon

Installed **HFS for Windows 7** yesterday. Did a reboot. Copied some files from my internal drive to external hfs drive. Did another reboot and rebooted to Mac. Mac worked fine. Then yesterday the battery went dead on my mac and the computer switched off.

This morning tried to boot into windows but got a BSOD as soon as I moved my mouse in the login screen. BSOD refeers to an error with service **HFSPLUS.SYS**

Now when I try to boot into mac (pressing alt while restarding) the mac drive isn's shown and I can only boot into **Windows 7 Safe Mode**.

**Cannot uninstall** HFS for Windows the uninstaller in control panel says:

> "THE WINDOWS INSTALLER SERVICE COULD
>   NOT BE ACCESSED. THIS CAN OCCUR WHEN
>   WINDOWS INSTALLER IS NOT CORRECTLY
>   INSTALLED".

**SETUP:** Intel Core 2 Duo, P8600 @ 2.40GHZ, 4GB RAM, **WINDOWS 7 ULTIMATE** 32 BIT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most logical route would be [fixing the Windows Uninstaller service](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/319624) and then properly removing Paragon HFS Driver through Control Panel.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing but it didn't actually solve the problem. After uninstalling I couldn't boot into safe mode either. Anyways now I have a clean install of both and I won't be installing HFS+ to windows no more. Their customer support hasn't responded yet ..

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem and found your question. I couldn't uninstall it from Windows because Windows would crash before it got half-way through. From safe mode, I deleted the following files to prevent HFS+ from loading:

```
c:\windows\system32\drivers\hfs*.sys
```

I then rebooted into normal mode, uninstalled the program, and found success again.

I'm never touching anything by Paragon again. Sheesh, that was a close call.